# posts_per_page option limits the number of Gallery items

Tags: posts, wp-query, query-posts, query, gallery

I have noticed that if I have a query where posts_per_page are set to 4, any (image) gallery that belongs to one of those posts will too have only 4 items (although when I create the gallery from Add new post the gallery has 10 images).

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to post the query code of both the post query and the gallery query; no one can really make a guess otherwise.

You can try using `<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>` after the post query to force a reset.

See http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query

Comment: But I don't really understand why a Gallery needs a query. After what may I reset the query? I would like every item in the gallery to appear, no matter there are 4 or 40 images in the gallery...Thanks

Comment: I'm just guessing at the problem; that's all I can do. You haven't posted code or anything to work with.